# Building two 2-D arrays from file data

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm tasked with writing two matrices to a file (which I have done), then read the data from the file to perform various calculations. What I am having difficulty with is rebuilding each matrix within a method to perform calculations. I decided to use an ArrayList of ArrayList, in order to get the 2-D matrix I need. Using a BufferedReader, I need to loop through one matrix, adding elements to one arraylist, then do it for a second matrix. I added the titles above the matrices to act as markers to find the matrix data I want to use. Is there better way to do it?

```
public void sum() throws IOException {

    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> matrixArray = new ArrayList<>();

    while(br.read() != -1) {
        ArrayList row = new ArrayList();

        //tried this, using two println spaces between matrices
        //but realized can't use readline this way     
        while(!br.readLine().equals("\n\n")) {
            row.add(br.read());
        }
        matrixArray.add(row);   
    }
```

The file data is of the form:

```
Matrix One
A  B
C  D

Matrix Two
A  B
C  D
```

--Update--from comment below

```
while(file.hasNext()) {
if(file.hasNext("Matrix One")){
    //Fill arraylist with row data until \n
    while(file.hasNextInt()) {
        row.add(file.nextInt());
    }  
        matrixOne.add(row);
    }
     else if(file.hasNext("Matrix Two")) {
       row.clear();
         while(file.hasNextInt()) {
             row.add(file.nextInt());
         }
         matrixTwo.add(row);
    }
   }
```

Comment: Do not clear the row. In stead, create a new one. Your arraylist of arraylist stores only references.

Comment: Is it allowed to write in JSON/XML format or Binary format?

Comment: @SaurabhJinturkar - No, only using Java. : /
Didn't think this would be difficult program -- turning out to be brain pain.

Comment: It is simple program. Decide how you will differentiate between two matrices. Add a line with stars or something similar. Example: ****<MatrixNo> <Dimension1><Dimension2>****. Use Scanner as mentioned in below answer. You can write binary object to the file using Java Serialization. So that while reading back you will read same object. There are many possibiities. You need to decide which one you want to go with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `java.util.Scanner` class. It is easier to use, and allows you to read line by line.

Once you get separate lines, you can call `String#split` method to separate the numbers using spaces.

This will give you an array of `String`s. You can now easily call `Integer.parseInt` method to retrieve `int` from the `String` and add it to your `ArrayList`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello Tanmay, thanks for the input and I was able to get started and build the first arraylist; however, when it comes to constructing the arraylist for the second matrix. My issue is distinguishing when the scanner object reaches the second matrix and to then store that data in the second matrix arraylist.

Comment: You can count how many numbers did you get in the first line (length of array returned by `String#split` method). That would be the dimension of your matrix. Assuming they are square matrices, you would know after how many rows would the next matrix start.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, it must deal with any matrix dimension. That is why I put the header above each matrix, hoping to use it as a tag to begin the new arraylist. Something like what I've updated in my original post above.

Comment: Even in that case, an explicit header is even easier to check for. Just use `String#contains` before splitting the read String.